# How to use List<MyTableObject> as a part of LINQ query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this LINQ query:

```
myDataObject.period = (from pe in myDataObject.myEDMXDataObject.MyTable
    join product in myDataObject.products
    on pe.ID equals product.ID
    where pe.LangID == myDataObject.chosenLang.LangID
    select pe).Distinct().ToList();
```

where myDataObject.products is of type

```
List<MyDataObject> products;
```

I get myDataObject.products with a similar LINQ query with join and where clauses, like this

```
myDataObject.products = (from tbl in MyTableName
    join tbl2 in MyTableName2
    on tbl1.ID equals tbl2.ID
    where /* where conditions here */
    select tbl).ToList();
```

It works properly. But I want to keep my code clean so instead of running all those conditions and the join again, I want to pass the data I have found already into the next LINQ query.

I am getting error like this:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
```

with inner exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyWPFApp.MyTableName'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Of course, the error is clear, I am doing something which is not allowed.

How can I send result from one LINQ query as a part of another LINQ query?

Comment: dont call ToList

Comment: Do you really need the Distinct? Using distinct in database is rather rare and often means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I can use GROUP BY instead, can I ?

Comment: That does not make a difference. Do not use the join here in the first place and you would not need deduplication. Use Exists instead (Any in Linq).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `JOIN` when what you should be using is a `WHERE`:

```
// select the distinct IDs 
var productIds = myDataObject.products.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().ToList();

myDataObject.period = myDataObject.myEDMXDataObject.MyTable
    .Where(pe => pe.LangID == myDataObject.chosenLang.LangID
              && productIds.Contains(pe.ID))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: products is of type List<MyTableName> where MyTableName is EF object inside my EDMX file. I need to compare by a field in this table not to search if an element of the same type exists in the list.

Comment: @Vlad Your join (`pe.ID == product.Id`) is what I'm doing with `productIds.Contains(pe.ID)` on the where clause.